Flink Sql Gateway: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/antlr/runtime/tree/Tree error when connecting with DBeaver
i've setup the Flink Sql gateway following the instruction here: https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.18/docs/dev/table/hive-compatibility/hiveserver2/
The connection from DBeaver works, but when i try to execute any command there's an exception:
2024-05-12 17:05:03,300 ERROR org.apache.flink.table.gateway.service.operation.OperationManager [] - Failed to execute the operation 9eff1eab-b754-4d05-b8ca-62d243bd6656.
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/antlr/runtime/tree/Tree
        at org.apache.flink.table.planner.delegation.hive.HiveParserFactory.create(HiveParserFactory.java:52) ~[flink-connector-hive_2.12-1.19.0.jar:1.19.0]
        at org.apache.flink.table.planner.delegation.PlannerBase.getParser(PlannerBase.scala:165) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableEnvironmentImpl.getParser(TableEnvironmentImpl.java:1261) ~[flink-table-api-java-uber-1.19.0.jar:1.19.0]
        at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableEnvironmentImpl.<init>(TableEnvironmentImpl.java:196) ~[flink-table-api-java-uber-1.19.0.jar:1.19.0]
        at org.apache.flink.table.api.bridge.internal.AbstractStreamTableEnvironmentImpl.<init>(AbstractStreamTableEnvironmentImpl.java:89) ~[flink-table-api-java-uber-1.19.0.jar:1.19.0]
        at org.apache.flink.table.api.bridge.java.internal.StreamTableEnvironmentImpl.<init>(StreamTableEnvironmentImpl.java:93) ~[flink-table-api-java-bridge-1.19.0.jar:1.19.0]
        at org.apache.flink.table.gateway.service.operation.OperationExecutor.createStreamTableEnvironment(OperationExecutor.java:430) ~[flink-sql-gateway-1.19.0.jar:1.19.0]
        at org.apache.flink.table.gateway.service.operation.OperationExecutor.getTableEnvironment(OperationExecutor.java:370) ~[flink-sql-gateway-1.19.0.jar:1.19.0]
        at org.apache.flink.table.gateway.service.operation.OperationExecutor.executeStatement(OperationExecutor.java:197) ~[flink-sql-gateway-1.19.0.jar:1.19.0]
        at org.apache.flink.table.gateway.service.SqlGatewayServiceImpl.lambda$executeStatement$1(SqlGatewayServiceImpl.java:212) ~[flink-sql-gateway-1.19.0.jar:1.19.0]
        at org.apache.flink.table.gateway.service.operation.OperationManager.lambda$submitOperation$1(OperationManager.java:119) ~[flink-sql-gateway-1.19.0.jar:1.19.0]
        at org.apache.flink.table.gateway.service.operation.OperationManager$Operation.lambda$run$0(OperationManager.java:258) ~[flink-sql-gateway-1.19.0.jar:1.19.0]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [?:1.8.0_392]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_392]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [?:1.8.0_392]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_392]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_392]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_392]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750) [?:1.8.0_392]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.antlr.runtime.tree.Tree
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387) ~[?:1.8.0_392]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:419) ~[?:1.8.0_392]
        at org.apache.flink.core.classloading.ComponentClassLoader.loadClassFromComponentOnly(ComponentClassLoader.java:150) ~[flink-dist-1.19.0.jar:1.19.0]
        at org.apache.flink.core.classloading.ComponentClassLoader.loadClass(ComponentClassLoader.java:113) ~[flink-dist-1.19.0.jar:1.19.0]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:352) ~[?:1.8.0_392]

I've already added the antlr-runtime-3.5.2.jar library to flink/lib folder.
I'm using Flink 1.19, local cluster no docker.
Any hint is appreciated
I've already added the antlr-runtime-3.5.2.jar library to flink/lib folder.
I'm using Flink 1.19, local cluster no docker.
Any hint is appreciated
